# "Resolving dependencies" when starting Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

When I tried to start a new rails project using rails 4.1.1, I got error messages that Actionmailer gem could not be installed, and I could not start my project. So I switched to rails 4.0.2, I got it started, but lots of "Resolving dependencies" , like below. What is this caused by? How should I resolve it? Should I worry about it? Thanks for any help!

```
create  
      create  README.rdoc
      create  Rakefile
      create  config.ru
      create  .gitignore
      create  Gemfile
      create  app
      create  app/assets/javascripts/application.js
      create  app/assets/stylesheets/application.css
      create  app/controllers/application_controller.rb
      create  app/helpers/application_helper.rb
      create  app/views/layouts/application.html.erb
      create  app/assets/images/.keep
      create  app/mailers/.keep
      create  app/models/.keep
      create  app/controllers/concerns/.keep
      create  app/models/concerns/.keep
      create  bin
      create  bin/bundle
      create  bin/rails
      create  bin/rake
      create  config
      create  config/routes.rb
      create  config/application.rb
      create  config/environment.rb
      create  config/environments
      create  config/environments/development.rb
      create  config/environments/production.rb
      create  config/environments/test.rb
      create  config/initializers
      create  config/initializers/backtrace_silencers.rb
      create  config/initializers/filter_parameter_logging.rb
      create  config/initializers/inflections.rb
      create  config/initializers/mime_types.rb
      create  config/initializers/secret_token.rb
      create  config/initializers/session_store.rb
      create  config/initializers/wrap_parameters.rb
      create  config/locales
      create  config/locales/en.yml
      create  config/boot.rb
      create  config/database.yml
      create  db
      create  db/seeds.rb
      create  lib
      create  lib/tasks
      create  lib/tasks/.keep
      create  lib/assets
      create  lib/assets/.keep
      create  log
      create  log/.keep
      create  public
      create  public/404.html
      create  public/422.html
      create  public/500.html
      create  public/favicon.ico
      create  public/robots.txt
      create  test/fixtures
      create  test/fixtures/.keep
      create  test/controllers
      create  test/controllers/.keep
      create  test/mailers
      create  test/mailers/.keep
      create  test/models
      create  test/models/.keep
      create  test/helpers
      create  test/helpers/.keep
      create  test/integration
      create  test/integration/.keep
      create  test/test_helper.rb
      create  tmp/cache
      create  tmp/cache/assets
      create  vendor/assets/javascripts
      create  vendor/assets/javascripts/.keep
      create  vendor/assets/stylesheets
      create  vendor/assets/stylesheets/.keep
         run  bundle install
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/..........
Resolving dependencies...
Using rake 10.3.2
Using i18n 0.6.11
Using minitest 4.7.5
Using multi_json 1.10.1
Using thread_safe 0.3.4
Installing tzinfo 0.3.41
Using activesupport 4.0.2
Using builder 3.1.4
Using erubis 2.7.0
Using rack 1.5.2
Using rack-test 0.6.2
Using actionpack 4.0.2
Using mime-types 1.25.1
Using polyglot 0.3.5
Using treetop 1.4.15
Using mail 2.5.4
Using actionmailer 4.0.2
Using activemodel 4.0.2
Using activerecord-deprecated_finders 1.0.3
Using arel 4.0.2
Using activerecord 4.0.2
Using bundler 1.6.2
Using coffee-script-source 1.8.0
Using execjs 2.2.1
Using coffee-script 2.3.0
Using thor 0.19.1
Using railties 4.0.2
Using coffee-rails 4.0.1
Using hike 1.2.3
Using jbuilder 1.5.3
Using jquery-rails 3.1.2
Using json 1.8.1
Using tilt 1.4.1
Using sprockets 2.11.0
Using sprockets-rails 2.0.1
Using rails 4.0.2
Using rdoc 4.1.2
Using sass 3.2.19
Using sass-rails 4.0.3
Using sdoc 0.4.1
Using sqlite3 1.3.9
Using turbolinks 2.3.0
Using uglifier 2.5.3
Your bundle is complete!
Use `bundle show [gemname]` to see where a bundled gem is installed.
```

Comment: conduced can you please highlight important points?

Comment: sorry just edited my messy post…can you help me?

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to SO! For starters, you should work on making your questions neater so more people will provide you with answers. The biggest thing you can do is put all your command line text into stackoverflow's "code sample" format. Just select the text you want to format and click the brackets `{}` above the text box you're using when typing your question. Alternatively, you can use the "control-k" or even "command-k" hotkeys.

Secondly, try to streamline all the terminal text. People tend to shy away from questions with a big block of text. For instance, in this question you don't really need anything before the "Resolving Dependencies" line. Generally, if your question is much longer than a page, you can probably cut it down.

Regarding your question, do not worry about the "Resolving dependencies" message. This is doing exactly what it sounds like: completing the necessary requirements for the program to run. A "dependency" is another program the program you're using needs to function. This is a normal process in Ruby on Rails and it's not harming your computer or throwing files somewhere you'll have to manually track down.

As for your ActionMailer issue, I'm not entirely sure what's going on. It sounds like a configuration issue. Perhaps if you can't resolve it, start a new question focused on that topic with more explicit information and hopefully someone more experienced will help out. Getting started and configuring your setup is a pain but get over that hump and you'll be glad you did it! Good luck!

Comment: Thanks so much Steve!! I tried to up vote you but I don't have enough reputation yet. Where can I find "accepted"? You are very helpful!!

Comment: @geekygirl76 I got a lot of help on here when I was first starting so it was a pleasure to pay it forward :). Don't worry about upvoting but I think you should be able to accept the answer. There should be a blank check mark by my answer that if you click, will become green and the answer will be accepted. Happy trails!